# Applying changes to multiple text boxes within a shape for all document shapes in MS visio 2016

Tags: vba, visio

I have an issue with the following code, when I run it it only changes the bottom text box font type. However, it changes all text boxes to size 12 pt.
Also it only apply the changes to the shapes in the active page, I want it to apply changes to the whole document.
Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
Dim doc             As Visio.Document
Dim pg              As Visio.Page
Dim shpObjs         As Visio.Shapes
Dim shpObj          As Visio.Shape
Dim celObj          As Visio.Cell

Dim i               As Integer

Set shpObjs = ActivePage.Shapes
Set doc = ActiveDocument
For i = 1 To shpObjs.Count
    Set shpObj = shpObjs(i)
    Set celObj = shpObj.Cells("Char.Size")
    celObj.Formula = "=12 pt."
    Set celObj = shpObj.Cells("Char.Font")
    celObj.Formula = "=234"
Next
 
 'Clean up
Set celObj = Nothing
Set shpObj = Nothing
Set shpObjs = Nothing
```

Comment: [cross-post](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=9826) which contain answer with code

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was [cross posted](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=9826) and the cross post already has a working answer.